# Set Delegate for each cell in a QTableView?

Tags: delegates, qtableview

class QTableView provide 3 interfaces for setDelegate:

1. setItemDelegate -- set delegate for whole QTableView
2. setItemDelegateForRow -- set delegate for given row
3. setItemDelegateForColumn -- set delegate for given column

question: if I just want to set delegate for a cell, how can I make it?

Comment: oh, I see, I pass row index and column index into class delegate to control the delegate only effect in cell of given row and column

Comment: where do you pass in the row index and column index ? In above 3 interfaces ?