# how to set a delegate for a single cell in QTableView?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtableview

class QTableView provide 3 interfaces for setDelegate:

- setItemDelegate -- set delegate for whole QTableView
- setItemDelegateForRow -- set delegate for given row
- setItemDelegateForColumn -- set delegate for given column

question: if I just want to set delegate for a cell, how can I make it?

for example , I got a Qtableview with two columns, The first column is set with a custom QCombobox delegate with items human and plant. The second column is also set with QCombobox delegate, but the optional items depends on the selection of the first column. it means each cell in the second column may has different delegates.

For example, if data(row=1, col=1) is selected as human from the combobox delegate, then cell(row=1, col=2) has a combobox delegate with items header, body, hand, foot; if data(row=2, col=1) is selected as plant from the combobox delegate, then cell(row=2, col=2) has a combobox delegate with items root, leaf, flower.

there is similar question but not answered yet, [Set Delegate for each cell in a QTableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45728525/set-delegate-for-each-cell-in-a-qtableview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The logic has nothing to do with a delegate per cell but to implement a logic based on the QModelIndex (which provides the row and column).

```py
import random
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QComboBox,
    QStyledItemDelegate,
    QTableView,
    QWidget,
)

OPTIONS = {
    "human": ["header", "body", "hand", "foot"],
    "plant": ["root", "leaf", "flower"],
}


class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QComboBox(parent)
        editor.currentTextChanged.connect(self.handle_commit_close_editor)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        if index.column() == 0:
            option = index.data()
            editor.clear()
            editor.addItems(list(OPTIONS.keys()))
            editor.setCurrentText(option)

        elif index.column() == 1:
            option = index.sibling(index.row(), 0).data()
            options = OPTIONS.get(option, [])
            editor.clear()
            editor.addItems(options)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        if index.column() == 0:
            option = editor.currentText()
            model.setData(index, option, Qt.DisplayRole)
            options = OPTIONS.get(option, [])
            model.setData(
                index.sibling(index.row(), 1),
                options[0] if options else "",
                Qt.DisplayRole,
            )
        elif index.column() == 1:
            option = editor.currentText()
            model.setData(index, option, Qt.DisplayRole)

    def handle_commit_close_editor(self):
        editor = self.sender()
        if isinstance(editor, QWidget):
            self.commitData.emit(editor)
            self.closeEditor.emit(editor)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setStyle("fusion")

    model = QStandardItemModel(0, 2)

    for i in range(4):
        option = random.choice(list(OPTIONS.keys()))
        item_1 = QStandardItem(option)
        item_2 = QStandardItem(random.choice(list(OPTIONS[option])))
        model.appendRow([item_1, item_2])

    view = QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.show()

    delegate = Delegate(view)
    view.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thanks very much, it works for me. I tried another way but it's not good as this one.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct solution for this, at least (that I know of) from PyQt5.

The problem is that all item view classes use a private (and unaccessible from PyQt) [`delegateForIndex`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview_p.h.html#_ZNK24QAbstractItemViewPrivate16delegateForIndexERK11QModelIndex) function that first of all checks the row and returns the delegate for that row if any exists, then it does the same for the column (again, if any exists) and finally returns the default delegate (the built-in delegate or the one set with the generic `setItemDelegate()`).

So, if you want to ensure that the delegate is **always** based on the row/column pair at first (and then "fall back" to some row or column dependant behavior), the only solution is to use a *unique* delegate, and then implement the relative functions based on the row/column position.